# Client Side Twitter Feed

Tags: javascript, twitter, web-applications

Making an informational website, and looking to have a twitter feed, showing the latest tweets an account made.  I understand that the twitter API supports [application only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only), however does this still not require a backend to protect API keys?

Is there a way to achieve this live feed with code exclusively on the client? (That is to say, no backend)  I would like to avoid scraping or other hack solutions, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen embedded timeline by Twitter, this method don't require api.
You can just embed client side.

Comment: Is it possible to reformat/style these?  I'd like to move away from the default looks and layout.

Comment: Not much options, I would suggest go for plugins. Lot of customizations are there. You can manipulate with Twitter feeds as you want.

Comment: Do you have any examples?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/10-twitter-plugins/ http://sonnyt.com/Tweetie/

Comment: best example I found http://www.queness.com/post/8567/create-a-dead-simple-twitter-feed-with-jquery